# How to "erase" numbers to only have the first digit of the number

Tags: java, spacing

If my variable is a random number between 0 and 6294 how would I get my output to ONLY print out the first variable?

My code for the random number is

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 6294);
```

Example, if it spits out 3542, I want it to just say 3. If it spits out 865, I want it to say 8. I am not to familiar with Java, but I was thinking it has something to do with line spacing? Something to do with the commands of %d, %f, %s? I am not to sure so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT**
No its part of a study guide that my professor put out. That's why its a number between 0-6294. I just don't know how to figure it out if the number is ever changing.

Comment: If you only need one digit, why are you randomizing on multi-digits numbers ?

Comment: This assumes that the OP doesn't need the hole number, however, maybe he needs 1 digit for this specific output but still has use for the whole number later in the code.

Comment: @Athamas Given his example, he is throwing away that random number immediately. He forgets about the other digits!

Comment: I don't get how "find out if the number is changing" leads to "only print first number". Why not just print the whole thing and see if its changing?

Comment: No its part of a study guide that my professor put out. That's why its a number between 0-6294. I just don't know how to figure it out if the number is ever changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's a good reason for truncating and not just generating a smaller random number (as others have suggested), you can parse the int to a string and get the first char/digit with the following:

```
//get random number
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 6294);

//print out just the first digit
System.out.println(String.valueOf(random).charAt(0));
```

Same as Mena's answer, but with `charAt(0)` instead of `substring(0,1)`

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution is to treat the number as a `String`, and retrieve the first character only.

Then you can safely convert it back to a number.

**For instance**

```
// assuming the output
int random = 3542;
// getting 1st character only
String truncated = String.valueOf(random).substring(0,1);
// parsing new int
int newRandom = Integer.parseInt(truncated); // ==> 3
```

**Note**

If you only want the first digit, chances are you don't need to randomize the way you currently do.

Comment: converting to and then from a String seems will not be too performant

Comment: @P.J.Meisch likely better than the math though.

Answer (score 1):

As @Berger said, it would be easier to just generate a random number between 1 and 10:

```
Random r = new Random();
int random = r.nextInt(10) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. The one that I like is dividing the number as long as the number is greater than 9:

```
int first_digit(int n) {
  while (Math.abs(n) > 9) {
    n /= 10;
  }
  return n;
}
```

You can do some basic math. The log in base 10 of a number gives the number of digits the number has. Dividing a number by 10 to the power of the number of digits minus one moves the decimal point to the left:

```
int first_digit_v2(int x) {
  return x / (int)Math.pow(10, (int)Math.log10(x));
}
```

It could be easier to just throw a random number between 1 and 9, but the probability distribution won't be the same as taking the first digit of the number. This is because of the [Benford's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law).

Answer (score 0):

Why doing all the detours? Why do you want to create a 4 digit number; when you only care about the first one?!

You see, in essence are asking for a random number between 0 and 6 then.
(or, following your idea of using 8 from 865; 0 and 9).

Just go for [Random.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) then, like:

```
int randomValueBetween0And9 = new Random().nextInt(7);
```

Hint: as JimmyB is correctly pointing out here: what you are doing here will influence the distribution of values. On the other hand: have you been thinking about *distribution* when you put together your example input?

Comment: Probably. Question is: does that really matter? And wouldn't it be **easier** to understand the distribution of such a "nextInt()" solution; compared to fetching "first char" of 3 or 4 digit string?!

Comment: I'm on the assumption that the OP chose this number generation scheme on purpose to *achieve* a certain distribution. Hence not much use in telling him to just use another distribution to simplify the output routine...

Comment: He didn't choose that number, it was given to him. And yes, in the narrow that makes my answer less usable. But in that sense ... maybe my answer is motivation to the OP to turn to the person who gave him that number - to understand what exactly the purpose of the whole thing is.

Comment: It is called Benford's Law, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law

Answer (score 0):

instead of truncating generate only what you need...
an int betwen 0 and 9

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
```